# DocumentDB connection in js: "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure-cosmosdb

I've been able to create the database and query it. Using Microsoft's tutorial on using node.js to query, I have been able to accomplish this with this code:

```
// Simple Query
    "use strict";
var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
var config = require("./config");
var url = require('url');

// use the previously saved config.endpoint and config.primaryKey to create a new DocumentClient
var client = new documentClient(config.endpoint, { "masterKey": config.primaryKey });

// These urls are how the DocumentDB client will find the right database and collection.
var HttpStatusCodes = { NOTFOUND: 404 };
var databaseUrl = `dbs/${config.database.id}`;
var collectionUrl = `${databaseUrl}/colls/${config.collection.id}`;

// Query JSON document collection
function queryCollection() {
    console.log(`Querying collection through index:\n${config.collection.id}`);

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.queryDocuments(
            collectionUrl,
            'SELECT VALUE gd.NFL FROM GamblersDenDB gd WHERE gd.id = "SanDiego"'
        ).toArray((err, results) => {
            if (err) reject(err)
            else {
                for (var queryResult of results) {
                    let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
                    console.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}`);
                }
                console.log();
                resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
};

queryCollection()
```

Running that js file in my command prompt works! It results in the output:

```
C:\Users\kenv\Desktop\DocDB Test>node SimpleQuery.js
Querying collection through index:
GamblersDenColl
        Query returned {"ID":"SDC","name":"Chargers"}
```

Great. So now I've transferred my code to my project's folder and try to run in the app with

```
taco run android --device
```

When I pull up the console, the first error that sticks out to me is

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined(…)
```

It's pointing to the line var `documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;` in my code.

Here is my complete js file code that's throwing the error:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    document.addEventListener( 'deviceready', onDeviceReady.bind( this ), false );

    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        console.log("Cordova is READY!");

        // Handle the Cordova pause and resume events
        document.addEventListener( 'pause', onPause.bind( this ), false );
        document.addEventListener( 'resume', onResume.bind( this ), false );

        $(".btnURL").on("click", function(){loadURL($(this))});
        function loadURL(theObj) {
            cordova.InAppBrowser.open(theObj.data("url"), "_blank", "location=yes");
        }


        //********* jQuery VARIABLES ***************//
        var $elBtnSaveName= $("#btnSaveName"),
            $elShowClients= $("#btnShowClients"),
            $elDivShow= $("#divShow"),
            $elFormClient= $("#formClient");

        //********** EVENT HANDLERS *****************//
        $elShowClients.on("click", queryCollection);

        //********************* DOCUMENT DB SECTION *********************************************************/
        var documentClient = require("documentdb").DocumentClient;
        var config = require("./config");
        var url = require('url');

        // use the previously saved config.endpoint and config.primaryKey to create a new DocumentClient
        var client = new documentClient(config.endpoint, { "masterKey": config.primaryKey });

        // These urls are how the DocumentDB client will find the right database and collection.
        var HttpStatusCodes = { NOTFOUND: 404 };
        var databaseUrl = `dbs/${config.database.id}`;
        var collectionUrl = `${databaseUrl}/colls/${config.collection.id}`;

        // Query JSON document collection
        function queryCollection() {
            console.log(`Querying collection through index:\n${config.collection.id}`);

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                client.queryDocuments(
                    collectionUrl,
                    'SELECT VALUE gd.NFL FROM GamblersDenDB gd WHERE gd.id = "SanDiego"'
                ).toArray((err, results) => {
                    if (err) reject(err)
                    else {
                        for (var queryResult of results) {
                            let resultString = JSON.stringify(queryResult);
                            console.log(`\tQuery returned ${resultString}`);
                        }
                        console.log();
                        resolve(results);
                        fnShowClientsTable(result.rows);
                    }
                });
            });
        };

        function fnShowClientsTable(data){
            var str = "<p><table id='tableResults'";
                str += "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th class='thEmpty'>&nbsp;</th></tr>" //added class to <th> for formatting
                    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // For X number of times worth of data...
                        str += "<tr><td>"  + data[i].doc.ID +  
                               "</td><td>" + data[i].doc.name + 
                               "</td><td class='btnPencil'>&#x270e;</td></tr>";
                    }
                str += "</table></p>";  // END table
                $elDivShow.html(str);   //Show string as HTML on screen

        } // END fnShowClientsTable

        //************************* END DOCUMENT DB SECTION ******************************************************/

    }; // END onDeviceReady()

    function onPause() {
        // TODO: This application has been suspended. Save application state here.
    };

    function onResume() {
        // TODO: This application has been reactivated. Restore application state here.
    };
} )();
```

I realize my other function to push it to a string for display in HTML is probably wrong (which I will most certainly have another post about that one :)) but right now I'm trying to determine how I can get past this first error.

Comment: "require" is available in node.js but not in browsers. My guess is that your android target is either a browser or like a browser. Typically, if you have something targeted at node.js but you want to run it in a browser or browser-like environment, you need something like browserify or webPack which will pull all of your dependencies into one big .js file. These tools will even provide browser equivalents to many of node.js standard libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Even though I got the error when running it directly on my android, I read up on browserify, got it installed, and now when I run it I am getting a different error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined" When I look at the line it complains about, it's the line in my js file that says: "var databaseUrl = `dbs/${config.database.id}`;" Do I not have the config file referenced properly? Again, all my code is posted above. Thanks!